# Java SSL keystore load

Tags: eclipse, sockets, ssl, keystore

I use Eclipse to make ssl socket server-client communication.
I am trying to use self signed certificate.

I make keystorage with Eclipse keytool. 
Than I try to load this keystorage:

```
String ksName = "herong.jks";
         KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
         ks.load(new FileInputStream(ksName), ksPass);
```

But I get following message:

> herong.jks (No such file or directory)

Name of keysotre is correct. May be I should do something else? now I only create keystore and certificate in key tool.

Comment: Probably the herong.jks file is not in the directory from which the code is being run.

Comment: You *get a FileNotFoundException* with that message. Don't you consider that relevant? It is.